# read numbers from text file python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a text file and return the contents of the text file. The textfile contains a matrix. When i  run my code with the file it just prints the first line.  My code looks right and i have searched online and cant seem to find the problem.

Code is:

```
def main():
    matrix = "matrix1.txt"
    print(readMatrix(matrix))


def readMatrix(matrix):
    matrixFile = open(matrix, "r")
    line = matrixFile.readline()
    while line != "":
        return line
        line = matrixFile.readline()
    matrixFile.close()

main()
```

Comment: Do you understand what `return` inside a function means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while line != "":
    return line # function ends
```

Maybe you mean

```
while line != "":
    print line
```

Answer (score 1):

`return` returns the value you pass it back to the caller and ends the function call. If you want to print each line, put the print statement instead of return.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing the `return` statement. When a function hits a `return`, control returns to the caller and does not return to the function. Thus, the most your function will do is read one line and return it, or close the file if the first line is empty.

Files in Python have a built-in iterator that will give you every line in the file, used like so:

```
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        [do something]
```

Note the use of the `with` statement. It will automatically close the file when its block is exited, which makes it the preferred way to deal with reading/writing files.

So what you want to do could be something like

```
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line: # Equivalent to if line == ''
            return
        else: # This else is actually redundant, but here so the flow is clear
            [do something]
```

Comment: i would use this way but this is for a class and we have not talked about with in class yet. I have to do it in a function with a while loop or a for loop.